# Vector Distance Calculation in Java - Optimization

Tags: java, optimization

As part of image processing function I need to calculate a sum of squares between
two lines in images.

This part of the code takes 96% of the run time:

```
for(int dx=0;dx<size;dx++) {
    int left = a[pa+dx];
    int right = b[pb+dx];
    int diff = (left & 0xFF) - (right & 0xFF);
    sum += diff*diff;
}
```

where:

- `a`, `b` are of type `byte[]`
- `sum` is `long`
- `size` is `int` and generally has big values (around 400)

Running Java 7 64 bit. I've tried to replace `a[pa+dx]` with stuff like `a[pa++]`
the performance is not better.

Exactly the same code written in C++ that does exactly the save runs
overall twice faster(!) and 
as far as I see there should be no significant reasons why wouldn't this Java
code be as fast especially when boundary checks can be moved out of the loop by
the compiler.

How can this stuff be optimized to perform as well as C++ code - as finally it is
integer arithmetic it shouldn't be much slower in Java

Edit: C++ sample looks like:

```
unsigned char const *srcptr=&a[pa];
unsigned char const *tgtptr=&b[pb];
for(int dx=0;dx < size;dx++) {
    int p1=*srcptr++;
    int p2=*tgtptr++;
    int diff = p1 - p2;
    sum += diff * diff;
}
```

I'd like to find out how to make HotSpot optimizer to create a code that
as fast as the C++ code shown above, finally it is quite simple and easy
to optimize lines.

Comment: Performance measurement in Java ist not that easy because of HotSpot. How did you measure it?

Comment: The function that takes most of the time, and if you remove these lines the code runs for almost no time.

Comment: You can try to run the code repeatedly in a kind of warm up to allow optimizations to kick in. I can't tell you how often, but probably around 1.000 to 10.000 times. After that you measure and see if there is a difference.

Comment: The code is warm CPU intensive and runs for about a minute...

Comment: Very difficult for anyone to help since we can't benchmark the isolated snippet you provided, so won't be able to test whether anything we suggest is any faster.

Comment: @DNA - I mostly care about tips. It is VERY simple code, there should be very few tricks that may improve it

Comment: Are you sure `sum` needs to be a `long`? Changing to an `int` gives a small improvement on my machine, though I can't be sure my benchmark is representative of your code.

Comment: Not really (unless images are larger than 32k pixels width that is unlikely), however switching it to int hadn't improved the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `& 0xFF`'s outside the loop.

Do this by calculating an `int[]`-version of both `a` and `b` and rewrite your loop using these.

Comment: You are right improved the run times from `1:20` to `0:53`. Also I used short instead of int as it reduces memory use and improves the performance. I thought that the compiler would be able to optimize to a single instruction like `movzbl` because it is just fetching unsigned byte!

Comment: Perhaps another JVM or -client/-server choice could.  Basically, express what you need as plainly as possible, giving the JVM the best working conditions.  I also think you should time it using `int`s and compare.

Comment: I checked both `int` and `short` and `short` was faster. Also the difference is more noticeable (without 0xFF) on Java 7, on Java 6 the run time is something like 1:10

Answer (score 2):

It's only small, but you don't need the `& 0xFF` to calculate the difference: The *difference* will be the same signed or unsigned.

```
100 - -1 = 101  // signed
228 - 127 = 101 // unsigned
```

Then it would be tighter loop body:

```
for (int dx = 0; dx < size; dx++) {
    int diff = a[pa+dx] - b[pb+dx];
    sum += diff*diff;
}
```

#### Edit:

There seems to be some confusion regarding signed vs unsigned byte arithmetic. If you doubt they are the same, execute this:

```
byte a = -128;
byte b = 127;
int diff = a - b;
System.out.println(diff); // -255

a = 127;
b = -128;
diff = a - b;
System.out.println(diff); // 255
```

The *reason* the range of diff values is greater than `byte` (-128..127), is that java automatically widens `byte` to `int` *before* the calculation because the destination variable is an `int`.

Comment: No it is not the same I need to substract the numbers as unsigned: 128-127 = 1; but (signed)(128) = -128 thus (singed -128 - 127) is much more

Comment: @Artyom Yes it *is* the same, because `128` is **NOT** a valid `byte` value! The `byte` range is `-128` to `127`

Comment: See, I deal with an image data where the values are unsigned bytes in range 0..255, however they are stored in Java bytes that are only singed.

Comment: But the _differences_ between the values are the same regardless if the datatype is signed or not.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The difference of unsigned bytes can go in range of [-255,255] which is not covered by `byte` type, that is why it differs.

Comment: @Artyom Dude, you're not "getting it". Diffing signed bytes will generate values in the range `[-255,255]` too! Because java automatically widens them to `int` before the calculation. Execute the code I've added to the answer and see for yourself

Comment: @artyom at the time of the minus you _are_ in int-land, and there is no need to look at bytes anymore.  Please at least _consider_ looking into what an answer from a person with almost four times as large a reputation as yourself is about - you might learn something.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen please take a look:  http://pastebin.com/sitgZr17 the first prints 66 which is incorrect for UNSIGNED bytes, the second one prints the expected result -190.

Comment: The java bytes are signed, but the REAL data is unsigned and I need the difference of the UNSIGNED data not the signed one, that is why I do the `& 0xFF` - to move signed value to unsigned one.

Comment: To make it more clear the vectors a and b are pixel values in range [0..255] stored is Java bytes, if Java had unsigned byte it would be stored using them, but Java do not have unsigned types. Thus I need to operate on these bytes as if they were unsigned.

Comment: @Artyom you still do not get it :(  The difference of the actual 8 bits _already present_ in your bytes is the same whether you are using signed or unsigned bytes to interpret the bits.

Comment: @Artyom if you disbelieve us, then provide an example of two `byte` values that have different differences with and without `& 0xFF`

Answer (score 1):

After I tested the same algorithm using different C++ compilers and different Java versions I've got to conclusion that GCC is **very** good compiler it optimizes the code better than intel and clang!

These are run-times of the same algorithm implemented in C++ and Java (when the line above is 96% of the run time:

```
Intel 12.1  1:58
GCC 4.6     0:43
GCC 4.4     0:43
Clang       1:20
Java 7      1:20
Java 6      1:23
```

Which shows that Java runs as fast as clang and Intel compiler for some reason does very bad job however gcc gives the best result, so I can't really expect from Java to run faster than
most of C++ compilers do.

Note this is the assembly generated by gcc:

```
.L225:
    movzbl  (%rcx), %r8d
    movzbl  (%rsi), %r10d
    addl    $1, %edx
    addq    $1, %rcx
    addq    $1, %rsi
    subl    %r10d, %r8d
    imull   %r8d, %r8d
    movslq  %r8d, %r8
    addq    %r8, %rax
    cmpl    %edx, %ebp
    ja      .L225
```

And this one generated by clang:

```
.LBB0_26:
    movzbl  (%r11), %r13d
    movzbl  (%r14), %esi
    subl    %r13d, %esi
    imull   %esi, %esi
    movslq  %esi, %rsi
    addq    %rsi, %rcx
    incq    %r11
    incq    %r14
    decq    %r12
    jne     .LBB0_26
```

What is the difference? GCC rearranges the instructions such that they can
run in parallel in the pipe-line, for example:

```
    movzbl  (%rcx), %r8d
    movzbl  (%rsi), %r10d
    addl    $1, %edx
    addq    $1, %rcx
    addq    $1, %rsi
```

Bottom line, Java run times are fine.

**Edit:** after providing `-xHost` option to Intel compiler (optimize for current CPU), the run time improved to 56s (using mmx instructions) but still not as fast as gcc, but little better than Java

Comment: Compilers usually have a lot of flags turning on and off optimizations.  Consider compiling with -O3 or better on all platforms.

Answer (score -1):

If "size" if size of array a or b you can avoid the for-condition:

```
try{
    for (int dx = 0; ; dx++) {
        ...
        ...
    }
}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException e){}
```

The two lines are  straight or curved? May you post a grafical representation of the problem, or a numeric example of the arrays? maybe there is a better geometrical solution?

Comment: You know that even if you don't check the range of dy the bounds are still checked by the array itself. Also the sum range usually ends before the actual end of the array.

Comment: Modern JVM's can optimize the range check outside the loop.